# Distributing Data Nodes Across Multiple Data Centers

Tags: hadoop, distributed-computing

Has anyone tried to test the performance of data nodes across multiple data centers? Especially over networks with small pipes. I can't seem to find too much information on it and the information I have found is either old (circa 2010) or proprietary (seems like DataStax has something). I know Hadoop supports rack awareness but like I said I haven't seen any documentation for tuning a system for multiple data centers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've tried it with a 12 x DataNode cluster arranged in a 2:1 ratio split between two data centers roughly 120 miles apart.  Latency between data centres was ~4ms across 2 x 1GbE pipes.

2 racks were configured in site A, 1 rack configured in site B.  Each "rack" had 4 machines in it.  We were basically testing Site B as a 'DR' site.  Replication factor was set to 3.

Long story short, it works, but the performance was really, really bad.  You definitely have to use compression on your source, map and reduce outputs in order to shrink your write I/O, and if the links between sites are used for anything else, you will get timeouts while transferring data.  TCP windowing would effectively limited our transfer to around 4MBps, instead of a potential 100MBps+ on a 1GbE line.

Save yourself the headache and just use distcp jobs to replicate data!